# Position LI-element at the bottom of UL

Tags: html, css

I am trying to craete a tab-like navigation menu using css and html. For this i am using an `<ul>`-element with `<li>` elements inside where i have set `display: inline-block` which has the desired effect.

However i want to have different height of the different `<li>`-elements, depending of wether they are selected or not and therefor i want them to start at the bottom of the parent `<ul>`-element.

I have tried with `bottom: 0px;` and `margin-bottom: 0px;` without any success.

I have been able to "force" them to the bottom by setting "margin-top = [height of ul-parent] - [height of li] but i would like to "attatch" them to the bottom instead of setting an offset to the top. How can i achieve this?

```css
.tab {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
li.selected {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab" id="left_menu">
  <li>Option A</li>
  <li class="selected">Option B</li>
  <li>Option C</li>
  <li>Option D</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dawmuzea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `vertical-align: bottom` and remove the `height`:

```
.tab {
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

li.selected {
  height: 30px;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6L0fhacb/**

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Any explanation to why i cant combine `height` with `vertical-align: bottom`?

Comment: @Cleared Not sure... But technically, you need `line-height` to adjust the height. Try that and let me know if it solves the `height` issue?